# tf.estimator.RunConfig does not parse environment variable TF_CONFIG

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

`tf.estimator.RunConfig` does not parse environment variable `TF_CONFIG`.
It only return the constants as below:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/run_config.py#L121-L151

[image]

We can not run distributed learning with `tf.estimator` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality in tf.estimator is still be worked on, and does not contain the functionality to use the TF_CONFIG environment variable.

For now, please continue using tf.contrib Estimator APIs.